# How do I force pytest to write color output?

Tags: pytest

How do I force pytest to show the results in color, even when writing to a pipe? There does not seem to be any command line option to do so.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

As of 2.5.0 py.test has the option `--color=yes`

As of 2.7.0, it should be also possible to do:

```
export PYTEST_ADDOPTS="--color=yes"
```

Answer (score 8):

The "py" library that pytest uses will not use color if it doesn't detect a terminal. I ended up making a change to it to allow setting an enviroment variable (`PY_FORCE_COLOR=1`) to force the color.

I submitted a PR for this: https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/py/pull-request/10/add-an-environment-variable-py_force_color

For now, I install my fork to do this:

`pip install hg+https://msabramo@bitbucket.org/msabramo/py@py_force_color`

Comment: as said there, i think we should introduce a direct ``--color=yes|no|auto`` option to pytest.

Comment: py.test now has the option that @hpk42 mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library that I have not tried but sounds promising. It's `pytest-rich`. See: https://github.com/nicoddemus/pytest-rich